# Pandas ValueError: buffer source array is read-only

Tags: pandas, cython, parquet

I am trying to read a Parquet file into a Pandas dataframe. Using the API's below (or even if I use pd.read_parquet() wrapper), I am hit by `ValueError buffer source array is read-only`.

Having searched around online, it seems to relate to Cython not supporting read-only buffer, however I couldn't find any solution on how to address this problem.

How can I read Parquet file into a Pandas dataframe when the API throws ValueError buffer source array is read-only?

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
   ...: import numpy as np
   ...: import pyarrow as pa
   ...: import pyarrow.parquet as pq

In [2]: table = pq.read_table('Parquet/Journal.parquet', columns=['SOURCE_CODE','YEAR','MONTH','AMOUNT'])

In [3]: df = table.to_pandas()

In [4]: df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 85326489 entries, 0 to 85326488
Data columns (total 4 columns):
AMOUNT         float64
SOURCE_CODE    category
YEAR           category
MONTH          category
dtypes: category(3), float64(1)
memory usage: 895.1 MB

In [5]: df.groupby(['SOURCE_CODE','YEAR','MONTH'])['AMOUNT'].sum()
```

Comment: As we don't have your data, it is not easy to verify the behavior. Can you make a self-contained example?

Comment: Also, which version of pandas are you using? Cython supports read only memory views since 0.28, thus the resent pandas-versions should not have this limitation (or at least it could be easily fixed  when your report the issue).

Comment: my pandas version is 0.23.4. Cython version is 0.29.2. Do I need to configure cython for read-only memory views?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in the latest release of pandas (0.23.x) and will be solved in pandas 0.24+. This issue was reported already by other users: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/23276 and is fixed though the following pull request: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/21688

For the sane fix, you need to wait for a new pandas release or manually install the git master. As a workaround you might be able to fix this by adding a dummy float column via `df['__dummy__'] = np.nan`. This will force pandas' BlockManager to reorder the float columns and should turn `AMOUNT` into a writable column.

Comment: Is this the only workaround at the moment?  Will copying the dataframe without the read-only flags work?

Comment: Copying does not work at the moment but in the next 2-3 days, Pandas 0.24 will released which fixes this.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this by adding a single before applying groupby.

`df = df.copy() #add this line`

`df.groupby(['SOURCE_CODE','YEAR','MONTH'])['AMOUNT'].sum()`